# how to plot graph of equation in react such as desmos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, equation

I trying to plot graph of equation  that get by input of user
like this in desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

[ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llOsT.jpg)

I found function plot (https://mauriciopoppe.github.io/function-plot/)
but it can not plot equation with e .

I want to know how to do it in another way .Can some one please explain or recomand me some idea to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
exp(x)
```

in the functionPlot it will look like this:

```
data: [
{
  fn: "exp(x)",
  derivative: {
    fn: "exp(x)",
    updateOnMouseMove: true
  }
}
```

]

to use the ln(x) function you can use:

```
log(x,exp(1))
```